# How to substract from current time 600seconds?

Tags: mysql, sql

I put only 15 seconds, but 60 is inaccesible [code below] Need your help guys! Thanks!!!!

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE users 
       SET ActivatedEmail = 1
         , Confirm = null 
     WHERE Confirm = '".$_GET['code']."' 
       AND now()-15 <= created_at 
    ";
```

Comment: `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 600 SECOND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`now()-15` is rather meaningless -- it converts a datetime to an integer and subtracts 15 from that.

You need to use `date_sub()` or interval arithmetic to do anything useful.  I would recommend:

```
now() - interval 15 second
```

I would also strongly encourage you to use parameters rather than munging query strings with constant values.